# Windows 10 Logging Me Off Every 5 Minutes

Tags: windows-10, screensaver, lock-screen, timeout, logout

I know that there are many similar questions on here and on other sites (trust me... I know...) I have been battling this for a while now and I simply cannot figure out why it is still logging me off after 5 minutes of inactivity.

I am using Windows 10 Pro 20H2 19042.867 Experience Pack 120.2212.551.0. This is a desktop computer, not on battery.

Some preface: I had to reinstall Windows for an unrelated reason and so I am setting everything back the way I had it before, I did not used to have this issue. After setting up, I had a Microsoft account login, I changed my account to login as a local account without a password so I could bypass the login screen.

After not touching the mouse or keyboard for 5 minutes the screen will go black and it will have my account picture and a button that says "Sign In". All I have to do is press space to reenter since I do not have a password. Earlier today it would happen every 2 minutes, but after changing the "Wait" setting in my Screen Saver settings I was able to get it up to 5 minutes. If I enter any number above 5 and click Ok, next time I open it it will be back at 5.

I tried everything I could find online, setting changes, Group Policy Edit changes, registry changes. I am now resorting to asking for help, so hopefully someone here has some idea as to what I am missing. Maybe this issue isn't "Screen Saver" or "Turn Off Screen" or "Machine Inactivity Timeout" related.

Here are some screenshots of my settings (currently most settings are configured via GPE so they are grayed out):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In addition to that, I have made the following changes to the Group Policy Editor:

```
Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / System / Logon
    Allow users to select when a password is required: Enabled
    Do not display the Getting Started screen: Enabled
    
Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / Control Panel / Personalization
    Do not display the lock screen: Enabled
    
Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / System / Power Management / Sleep Settings
    Specify the system hibernate timeout (plugged in): Enabled (599940)
    Require a password when a computer wakes (plugged in): Disabled
    Specify the system sleep timeout (plugged in): Enabled (599940)
    Allow applications to prevent automatic sleep (plugged in): Enabled
    Allow applications to prevent automatic sleep (on battery): Enabled
    Allow automatic sleep with Open Network Files (plugged in): Disabled
    Allow automatic sleep with Open Network Files (on battery): Disabled
    Specify the system hibernate timeout (on battery): Enabled (599940)
    Require a password when a computer wakes (on battery): Disabled
    Specify the system sleep timeout (on battery): Enabled (599940)
    Specify the unattended sleep timeout (plugged in): Enabled (599940)
    Specify the unattended sleep timeout (on battery): Enabled (599940)
    
Computer Configuration / Administrative Templates / System / Power Management / Video and Display Settings
    Turn off the display (plugged in): Enabled (599940)
    Turn off the display (on battery): Enabled (599940)
    
Computer Configuration / Windows Settings / Security Settings / Local Policies
    Accounts: Limit local account use of blank passwords: Disabled
    Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit: 599940
    
Computer Configuration / Windows Settings / Local Policies / Security Options
    Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit: 599940
    
User Configuration / Administrative Templates / Control Panel / Personalization
    Enable screen saver: Not configred
    Password protect the screen saver: Disabled
```

As well as the following registry changes:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0]
"Attributes"=dword:00000002

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Control Panel\Desktop]
"ScreenSaveActive"="0"
"ScreenSaveTimeOut"="599940"
"ScreenSaverIsSecure"="0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization]
"NoLockScreen"=dword:00000001
```

If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it. I would just like my computer to function the way I expect it to, I cannot believe Microsoft makes it so hard to accomplish such a basic change...

Comment: Is this your office laptop?

Comment: This is my personal desktop computer

Comment: One report that is missing is that of [powercfg -energy](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5148-create-power-efficiency-diagnostics-report-windows-10-a.html). This creates an HTML file that you could post online for us to see.

Comment: @harryme Here is my report: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xOyOx40uKSEycY6VMUk2Sa5MjL9BCvJN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: One more please: `powercfg /a`. What is your computer model? Are you using the latest BIOS?

Comment: powercfg /a  - 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GAoyNRNrivrlcInFj6u8mHtJeRodiC0X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I built my computer myself, it has an AsRock Z390 Pro4. This didnt happen before though on the same hardware, but after I reinstalled Windows it started happening. From here https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z390%20Pro4/index.asp#Download I have only installed the INF drivers, the LAN driver causes system instability for me. *Edit: and installed the Realtek audio drivers

Comment: Effectively, all Sleep options have been disabled, so this might be caused by software. If it's happening in a regular manner, see if it arrives when booting in Safe mode where only Microsoft software runs. You could also check the Event viewer at *Windows Logs > Security* for events [4634](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4634) and [4647](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4647). See [explanation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4634).

Comment: It happens at exactly 5 minutes, which is the maximum value I could set my screen saver "Wait" to before I changed it with the GPE. Even when the screensaver was disabled it would happen at 5 minutes, or 2, or 1 minutes depending on what I set it to, moved it off of None, change the time, back to None. Normally you should be able to set that above 5 right? I would set it to 9 or 15 and save then open it again and it was 5. Making it higher and locked in GPE also doesnt seem to affect that max.

Comment: Does it happen when [booting in Safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a ;possibility that the *wrong* power plan was edited? In your thorough documenting of Power Options, the one dialog that was not shown was selection of the plan currently in use. Did you edit the values for a different plan than the one currently selected?

[image: Power Plans]

If all else fails, though, there are some small applications that emulate key events to prevent shutdown, such as [Don't Sleep](http://softwareok.com/?Download=DontSleep), and [Caffeine](http://zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine), both free. They're also handy to prevent long-running operations from timing out.

Comment: I had 'High performance' selected which is where the screenshots were taken. I have created a new custom power plan based off that one and the values are the same. I will see if that makes any difference. Thank you.

Comment: It did not help. It doesn't seem to happen if I have a Youtube video open on the screen, if that says anything. I could just keep a Youtube video open on the screen at all times...

Comment: But it does happen if there is a Youtube video playing but it is not in the foreground.

Comment: @ZGorlock, there is a workaround other than YouTube: apps such as Don't Sleep, https://www.softwareok.com/?Download=DontSleep and Ceffeine, https://zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/, though it *should* be possible to fix the issue without it.

Comment: yes I was aware that things like that existed but I would use them as a last resort. It's like it is ignoring everything that I have set, it is personal now haha

Comment: Agreed. Grrrr... It's Microsoft or me, only one of us is gonna walk out this here server room.

Comment: I ended up installing Caffeine and it works fine for me. Thanks to everyone who had useful answers. I am sure there is a way to fix it within Windows but I just couldn't spend anymore time on it.

Answer (score 0):

If some friend of yours had access to this computer, he would been able to install a simple program in the background, or called by the system, that is logging you off.

So I would check all running processes and entries in automatic start of apps for such a program.

Seems like an annoying joke.

Comment: No really no one has been on my PC, I work from home and it is in my room.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the Event viewer at Windows Logs > Security for events
[4634](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4634)
(An account was logged off) and
[4647](https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4647)
(User initiated logoff).
The event description will include the process which initiated the logoff,
so may identify the problem.
For an explanation of the difference between the two events, see
[this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4634).

See also if the problem arrives when
[booting in Safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234)
where only Microsoft software runs.
If it doesn't happen, then this is caused by some installed third-party product,
and you may use
[Autoruns for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
to turn them off in bunches until you find the problem.

If the problem still arrives in Safe mode, then Windows is corrupted.

Run CMD as administrator and check system correctness (see
[link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)):

```
dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
sfc /scannow
```

If no problem is found, do a
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html),
to return Windows to a known state.